# How to change the Equations in string format to normal equations in Python?

Tags: python

I have a set of equations in string format as given below. Need to assign some value to the left-hand side variable (In the below example: rsp, esp). Then have to calculate and store the results on the right-hand side variable (i.e., rax, esp, rsp).

Example:

`rax = rsp`

`esp = esp - 0x4`

`rsp = rsp - 0x30`

Though I have used the `eval` function in python, it is throwing me an error message as it won't support `=`. Could someone please help me to find the answer?

Comment: The answers to this question are not quick and easy. Time to read up on abstract syntax trees, parsers, and interpreters. I have a reading list on my website: https://www.msreverseengineering.com/program-analysis-reading-list/ You can expect to spend at least weeks studying these subjects before you feel comfortable doing what your question asks.

Comment: @RolfRolles, thank you for your comment. I have found the solution to the question which I posted. With the help of "locals" and "globals" in python programming, this can be solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of "locals" and "globals" in python programming, this can be solved